# How to parse HTM into NSString objects that contain segments of HTML code rather than its content

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parsing, html-parsing

I have a htm file (exported from Excel using UTF-8 encoding) containing a table of Japanese characters and phonetic symbols. [Get a sample file here.](http://www.filedropper.com/kanji)

I've added the htm file into my Xcode project and now wish to create NSString objects containing the html code for each cell in the table (i.e. the html between `<td> </td>)`. I will be using these NSStrings to display these Japanese characters in a UIWebView later (have to use HTML to preserve the ruby text).

For example, the following table cell from the htm file:

```
  <td><ruby>朝<rt>あさ</rt></ruby><ruby>御飯<rt>ごはん</rt></ruby></td>
```

needs to be put into an NSString like this:

```
NSString *string1 = @"<ruby>朝<rt>あさ</rt></ruby><ruby>御飯<rt>ごはん</rt></ruby>";
```

Lastly, as these NSStrings are parsed/created I also need to add in some basic html formatting  as per below:

```
NSString *string1 = @"<div align='center' style='font-size:40px;'><ruby>朝<rt>あさ</rt></ruby><ruby>御飯<rt>ごはん</rt></ruby>";
```

I'll then put the string objects in an array and display them in a UIWebView as needed.

I've looked at a few HTML parsers, including hppl, but they all seem to grab the content that is within the html rather than segments of html code.

Anybody know how I can create these NSStrings from the htm file?